# What are the PCB design guidelines to achieve a noise floor of 0.1 mV? What are the significant measures to reduce the noise floor to 10 micro-V?

Tags: pcb-design, photodiode, low-noise-amplifier

I am designing a photodiode (PD) readout circuit containing the PD, I-V op-amp, the amplifier's 2.5 V regulated supply, and associated resistors & capacitors. The op-amp's output will be connected to an ADC evaluation board via an SMA connector. The PD's output varies between 4 different values at 400 Hz, while we sample it at 4 kHz. The PD output when converted to voltage will be 2.2-2.4 V. In this PCB, I'm trying to achieve a noise floor of 0.1 mV. For that purpose, I aim to do/did the following:

1. Use a wall-mount AC-DC adapter (9 V), which will connect on the board to LDO voltage regulators (9 to 5 V, and then 5 to 2.5 V) rather than a switching regulator/s.
2. The op-amp is chosen with a high PSRR to limit power supply variations from reaching the op-amp's output.
3. The feedback resistor for the op-amp is chosen to be a thin-film SMD with a tolerance of ±0.05%.
4. All components are surface mount, so as to avoid the extra trace length in DIP packages
5. Follow good PCB layout tips such as: having an uninterrupted ground plane (between two signal planes if needed), keeping trace lengths short so as to reduce voltage drop, using bypass capacitors close to the op-amp's supply pin, use vias to connect to ground rather than routing to a central point, use guard rings.

My queries:

1. Are the above techniques sufficient to limit noise to 0.1 mV? If not, please let me know further methods.
2. What techniques should be employed to lower the noise floor even further, to 10 micro-V?

Comment: What is the bandwidth of your amplifier? What is the bandwidth of interest? What is the noise power spectral density of the photodiode in the bandwidth of interest? What filtering can you use to reduce the noise bandwidth? What is the common-mode output noise of the power supply looking like?

Comment: The amplifier has a bandwidth of 5kHz at my desired gain. The highest frequency component in the photodiode output is 400 Hz, to sample this properly I'm sampling at 4 kHz. Apart from this, the photodiode output has a DC component. So, that must put my bandwidth of interest and the system bandwidth at 4 kHz, right? The photodiode has an NEP of 1.4e-15 W, which would put the noise power in 4 kHz to be 88.5 fW. I hadn't thought of filtering to reduce noise - but isn't this achieved by the op-amp itself (due to the 5 kHz bandwidth)? The output noise voltage of the power supply is 100 uV,isthatit?